# can be change the url in request dispatcher

Tags: jsp, servlets, requestdispatcher

Is it possible to change the url  in case of request dispatch .

This is my code

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException, ServletException
{

 List<HomePageServicesDescription> data= HomePageServicesDescriptionDB.showHomePageServicesDescription();
 req.setAttribute("description", data);

 req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(req,res);

 }
```

So when see it in web browser so it give the url=`http://localhost:8888/url-mapping` of servlet.
but i want that url=`http://localhost:8888/index.jsp`. how it can be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got  the answer

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) 
    throws IOException, ServletException
{

    List<HomePageServicesDescription> data = HomePageServicesDescriptionDB.showHomePageServicesDescription();
    req.getSession().setAttribute("description", data);

    res.sendRedirect("index.jsp");

}
```

And in index.jsp

```
List<HomePageServicesDescription> data= (List<HomePageServicesDescription>) session.getAttribute("description");
```

Its perfectly work

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing `HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect()` instead of `RequestDisaptcher.forward()`. Any parameters you want to send can be sent as Query Parameters.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) 
        throws IOException, ServletException
{

   List<HomePageServicesDescription> data =
             HomePageServicesDescriptionDB.showHomePageServicesDescription();
    req.setAttribute("description", data);

    res.sendRedirect("index.jsp?description="+data);

 }
```

Comment: thankyou again sir but i want to set the request attribute. Sir there is any way plz help me.

Comment: Send Query parameter and access it as ServletRequest.getParameter("description") on redirected servlet. What is the issue?

Comment: sir it is not working in jsp page                List<HomePageServicesDescription> list= (List<HomePageServicesDescription>) ServletRequest.getParameter("description"); it give the error

Comment: i already post the servlet & jsp code <% List<HomePageServicesDescription> list= (List<HomePageServicesDescription>) ServletRequest.getParameter("description");
if (!data.isEmpty()) {
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {        HomePageServicesDescription description = data.get(i);
%>
<div class="contentsection">
<div class="title"><%=description.getTitle()%></div>
<p class="imgText"><%=description.getDescription()%></p>          <div class="read"><a href="<%=description.getHref()%>">Read More</a>
</div></div>
<%}
} else {%>
<jsp:include page="error.jsp" / <%}%>

Comment: ServletRequest is class, you should be giving the object variable which is request. So it should be request.getParameter("description")

Comment: sry sir it is not working it give the exception and the url is http://localhost:8888/index.jsp?description=[Title%20:%20Portal%20/%20eCommerce,%20Description%20:%20%3Cspan%20style=%22color:%20rgb(102,%20102,%20102);%20text-align:%20justify;%20%22%3EOur%20development%20team%20build%20solutions%20that%20work%20across%20user%20communities%20and%20devices(different%20types)%20right%20out%20of%20the%20box.&nbsp;%3C/span%3E%3Cbr%] like this

Comment: what is the exception you are getting